# Getting node name using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am having the following xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <report>
  <sampleduration>900</sampleduration>
  <network>
    <gateway>
      <red>103</red>
      <blue>105</blue>
      <black>120</black>
    </gateway>
  </network>
 </report>
```

My requirement is to get list of node names and their values. However i am able to get list of values but not their node names.

> name(//gate) - prints gate;
> //gate/*/name() - prints correctly;

Is there any another way to achieve this apart from above xpath working code. It would be better if we can use functions from here - https://github.com/antchfx/xpath

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution can be achieved with XPath-2.0:

```
//*/concat(name(),' - ',text()[1])
```

But the output is not in document order.
I don't know of any XPath-1.0 solution.